# "A Better Us" or "A better We"?

Tags: grammaticality

At the gym I use, I pass a promotional poster that shows a group of people on life cycles. The caption reads "A Better Us."  Every time I see it, I wonder, "Is this Ok?"  "us" is the object form of "we."  Is there an implied missing part that Makes "us" ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide the appropriate *transitive verb* of your choice with the phrase as its object:

> *Build* **a better us**
>  *Behold* **a better us**
> Exercise *makes* **a better us**

But bear in mind that even as the complement of a copulative verb, we prefer the objective case when strict application of grammar rules requires the nominative.  Must people would say

> This is **a better us**

and not "a better we," just as they would say when the gang comes back

> It's us.

instead of "It's we.

Comment: Ok, so it's a matter of preference that is generally acceptedk.  In your first example, it's an imperative, as in "You / We" build a better us?

Comment: @michael_timofeev Yeah, as if the sweat-stained participants we're begging the trainers, "Build a better us."